# Javascript/jQuery mouseover and mouseout Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure how to solve an issue I'm having at the moment. I'm building a Javascript and PHP powered image gallery. The basic div structure is that I have a div that contains the gallery as a whole, one for the image being displayed, and a div containing a "previous button", and another containing a "next button."

The next/previous buttons are positioned on the left/right side at the bottom of the image container div (the gallery container is set to relative position, the button divs to absolute). By default they are made non-visible using jQuery, and become visible when you hover over the image container div. The issue I'm having is when you hover over the container div, and then over the arrows, the transition effect re-plays and I'm not sure how to fix that using HTML/CSS/JS. My current structure for the divs is

```
<div id="galleryContainer">
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="img" />
  </div>
  <div id="leftArrow"></div>
  <div id="rightArrow"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so my fadein/out effect stops acting all bugged when I hover over the next/prev buttons? I've tried a bunch of combinations of using "onmouseover" listeners when I establish the div, to using jQuery listeners, to trying to change up the hierarchy of the drivs. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is my current jQuery code of what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#imageContainer").mouseover(function()
{
    $("#leftArrow").fadeIn();
    $("#rightArrow").fadeIn();
});

$("#galleryContainer").mouseout(function()
{
    $("#leftArrow").fadeOut();
    $("#rightArrow").fadeOut();
}); 
});
```

When I put the buttons inside of the imageContainer it still does the fade bug/effect.

Comment: Yes, could you please add your JavaScript code and any relevant CSS?

Comment: If you can replicate the problem in a www.jsFiddle.net it will be easiest for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [$.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)  and [$mousenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) A problem is that the mouseout and mouseover events bubble. Then, your handlers are called when those events are fired on #galleryContainer when it happens in any of its descendants

http://jsfiddle.net/z2Y8a/20/

```
$("#imageContainer").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#leftArrow").fadeIn();
    $("#rightArrow").fadeIn();
});

$("#galleryContainer").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#leftArrow").fadeOut();
    $("#rightArrow").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The $.mouseleave event listener was exactly what I needed!

Comment: You should also use `$.mouseenter` so it doesn't try to fade in when you move your mouse over the image. You won't see anything, but you're still wasting cycles

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpreted your question without seeing any code.. Let me know.
I added colors to the divs so you can see which is located where.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2Y8a/19/

```
<div id="galleryContainer" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:green;">
    <div id="imageContainer" style="width:50px;height:100px;background:blue;">
        <div style="height:75px;">
            <img src="img" />
        </div>
        <div id="leftArrow" style="width:25px;height:25px;background:red;float:left;display:none;">L</div>
        <div id="rightArrow" style="width:25px;height:25px;background:yellow;float:left;display:none;">R</div>
    </div>
</div>​

<script>
    $("#imageContainer").hover( function()
    {
        $("#leftArrow").toggle();
        $("#rightArrow").toggle(); 
    });​
</script>
```

-- EDIT --

```
$("#galleryContainer").hover(function()
{
    $("#leftArrow").toggle();
    $("#rightArrow").toggle();
});
```

Comment: @LeonP edited my answer, that should fix your problem. Don't forget to accept the answer that solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It would not flicker if your arrows are inside of your image container. Or maybe put the show arrow effect in the main gallery container. Basically when your mouse laves the image container, it will trigger the mouseout. When I say leave I mean in code sense, visually it does not leave because you have it positioned differently but in code sense, your mouse left the image container and entered the arrow containers