# KineticJS - Custom mouse cursor style using url

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I am trying to change the cursor style using PNG image, here is my script:

```
   group.on("mouseover", function(){
          document.body.style.cursor =  "url('../../Content/icons/zoom_in.png'), auto";
        //  document.body.style.cursor =  "pointer";
        });
   group.on("mouseout", function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    });
```

I tested the script using change to pointer, and it works well.  I would appreciate your suggestions and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, the PNG file should be converted to CUR file, I used nice program called AniFX's.  The script is:

```
group.mouseenter(function(){
    document.body.style.cursor =  "url('../../Content/icons/zoom_in.cur'), auto";
    //  document.body.style.cursor =  "pointer";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume *group* is a JQuery object. I would give mouseenter/mouseleave a go.

```
group.mouseenter(function(){
    document.body.style.cursor =  "url('../../Content/icons/zoom_in.png'), auto";
    //  document.body.style.cursor =  "pointer";
});
group.mouseleave(function(){
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
});
```

see [Javascript/jQuery mouseover and mouseout Event Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558174/javascript-jquery-mouseover-and-mouseout-event-listeners)

Comment: Thanks, actually it is a KineticJS group (canvas).

Comment: agh, my bad! I read the tags but obviously not the title... sorry

Comment: Actually you have read the title, I just edit it because of the question.  Thanks a million